# MIB File How to generate table header and definition files?

Tags: c, snmp, mib

I have use the following command and got the error msg

```
  mib2c -c mib2c.column_defines.conf programTable
```

ERROR: failed to open programTable_columns.h
  at /usr/local/share/snmp//mib2c.column_defines.conf:1

i Have used the all the commands but got the same error message

Doubts

```
1)How to create a table for the mib file
2)How to Generate the .c and .h file
```

Comment: It looks like the error says that the .conf file refers to a .h file that doesn't exist.  Can you look in the .conf file?

Comment: What i have to add in the .conf file
i have already addedd in the snmp.conf
   mibs +DRCVR-MIB
   mibs +ALL

Comment: Please keep in mind that when you write "i Have used the all the commands", it is not obvious to us, your readers, which commands these are. Please try to explain in more detail what you have tried.